# Suppressing a warning in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'd like to supress the Forms error:

```
WUO-709 [] Cells; Exception com.jacob.com.ComFailException: 
A COM exception has been encountered []', the Forms error is 'FRM-40735 [] ORA-06502
```

and display my custom message instead. Is there anyway to do this? 
Thanks for your help!

Ps. I tried catching it using an Forms wide `on-error` trigger which is printing my message if the `error_code = 40375` and also setting the `message_level = 25`. But both didn't work :(

Comment: this message is not  due to an internal forms module error, whereas that's related with some interaction with the applet and your file system. This link may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951145/jacob-com-jacob-com-comfailexception-cant-co-create-object

Comment: I know where the error is coming from ( I'm exporting data using clientole2 to Excel and the user is closing the window before its done) and thats ok. I just want something less cryptic to be displayed as error instead of two popup windows. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ON-ERROR` trigger and/or `ON-MESSAGE` trigger and in these triggers fetch the error and do something with it you like and with the other errors show an error.

Comment: I tried an on_error trigger but that did not work. Its showing the above error and then after that showing my message.The on_message trigger is not even showing my message.